# Spring data mongodb removes a positional operator from "$unset" update query part

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection of users:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e12"),
        "token" : "8c9f8cf4-1689-48ab-bf53-ee071a377f60",
        "categories" : [
                DBRef("cue_categories", ObjectId("544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e10")),
                DBRef("cue_categories", ObjectId("544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e11"))
        ]
}
```

I want to find all users who have (let's say) `ObjectId("544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e10")` category and remove it (because this category was deleted and I don't want users to refer to it anymore).

The valid query to do it in JSON format would be:

```
db.users.update({  
    categories:{  
        $in:[  
            DBRef("cue_categories", ObjectId("544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e10"))
        ]
    }
},
{
    $unset:{
        "categories.$":true
    }
})
```

Here's a Spring mongodb query:

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categories.$id").in(categoryIds));

Update update = new Update();
update.unset("categories.$");

operations.updateMulti(query, update, User.class);
```

In order to make an appropriate DB reference I have to provide a list of category IDs, each category ID (in `categoryIds`) is an instance of `org.bson.types.ObjectId`.

The problem is that the result query turns out to be without a positional operator:

> DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Calling update using
>   query: { "categories.$id" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" :
>   "544ab933e4b099c3cfb62e10"}]}} and update: { "$unset" : { "categories"
>   : 1}} in collection: users

So the update part must be `{ "$unset" : { "categories.$" : 1}}`

**P.S.**
I managed to get around by falling back to the plain Java driver use

```java
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("categories.$id", new BasicDBObject("$in", categoryIds));
DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$unset", new BasicDBObject("categories.$", true));
operations.getCollection("users").updateMulti(query, update);
```

But my question still remains open!

**P.S.S.**
My case is very similar to [Update Array Field Using Positional Operator ($) Does Not Work](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-862) bug and looks like it was fixed for versions **1.4.1** and **1.5**. That being said I use [`spring-data-mongodb` version **1.5.1**](http://oi61.tinypic.com/m2asj.jpg). And I'm confused. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: This looks more like a bug report. I suggest filing it on the Spring JIRA.

Comment: Filed issue [DATAMONGO-1077](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1077) for this one.

Comment: hey @dVaffection [PR #235](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/235) tackles the problem just in case you want to give it a try.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl As far as I see now it is in the master branch. How can I try it? Notice I use Gradle and [`spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`](http://oi61.tinypic.com/m2asj.jpg)

Comment: you should be able to download the snapshot `compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '1.7.0.DATAMONGO-1077-20141028.072736-2')` already from [repo.spring.io](http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use positional $ operator with unset as per MongoDB documentation. It will set the value as Null. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/